# MUI Autocomplete expanded dropdown narrowing after select few items

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

using material ul v5, initial look of autocomplete is fine width of search field and dropdown same..

after select few items, width of dropdown reduced from 655 to 639, and I dont know why.

[image]

How can I resolve this? and why its happening at first place?

This is source code of AC, nothing special;

```
return (
    <div style={style}>
      <Autocomplete
        noOptionsText={noOptionsText}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(o: IAutocompleteGroupOptions, value: IAutocompleteGroupOptions) =>
          _selectedOptions.find(
            (op: IAutocompleteGroupOptions) => value.type === o.type && value.id === o.id,
          ) as any
        }
        open={open}
        defaultValue={_selectedOptions}
        value={_selectedOptions}
        onChange={(
          event: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>,
          value: IAutocompleteGroupOptions[],
          reason: AutocompleteChangeReason,
        ) => {
          let subItemss: IAutocompleteGroupOptions[] = []
          if (reason === 'selectOption') {
            const addedItem = value[value.length - 1]
            if (addedItem.childItems && addedItem.childItems?.length > 0) {
              subItemss = autoSelectChildItems(addedItem.id)
            }
            handleAddUserGroup([...value, ...subItemss])
          }

          if (reason === 'removeOption') {
            const removedItem = selectedOptions.filter(f => !value.map(m => m.id).includes(f.id))[0]
            if (removedItem.childItems && removedItem.childItems?.length > 0) {
              value = value.filter(f => f.parentId != removedItem.id)
            }
            handleAddUserGroup(value)
          }
        }}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        multiple
        id="user-groups-autocomplete"
        classes={{ ...classes }}
        forcePopupIcon={false}
        options={dataOptions.sort((a: IAutocompleteGroupOptions, b: IAutocompleteGroupOptions) => {
          return -b.type.localeCompare(a.type)
        })}
        groupBy={option => option.type}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
        renderTags={renderTags}
        renderInput={params => {
          params.InputProps.startAdornment = (
            <>
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <SearchOutlined htmlColor={color.shade30} />
              </InputAdornment>
              {params.InputProps.startAdornment}
            </>
          )
          params.InputProps.endAdornment = null
          return (
            <TextField
              className={classes.input}
              placeholder={placeHolderText}
              {...params}
              variant="outlined"
              type="text"
              onFocus={onFocus}
              onBlur={onBlur}
            />
          )
        }}
        renderOption={renderOption}
      />
```